# Is it correct to say "via a"?

Tags: articles

Is it considered proper English to say something like this?

> I called her via a telephone.

Or should the indefinite article be omitted entirely?

> I called her via telephone.

If the indefinite article is to be omitted, are there any cases in which it should not be? Or, does it even matter?

Comment: How about "I called her by telephone."

Comment: That would work, but I'm curious about "via", specifically.

Comment: It's the following noun that decides the choice of determiner, not the preposition *via*. Some preposition phrases, do lead to the dropping of determiners (e.g., *in hospital*), but this isn't the case here.

Comment: I would avoid the issue and just text her.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you look at the *Merriam-Webster* dictionary, two of the example usages for *via* are as follows:

> He did some research via computer.
>
> We went home via a shortcut.

So the second example shows you can certainly use *a* after *via*. ("We went home via shortcut" sounds wrong to me.)

However, I would say *via telephone.* This usage is closer to *via computer,* because *telephone* here refers not to a specific telephone, but to the general medium of telephony. Similarly, you would go somewhere *via train* or *via superhighway*, if you are talking about trains or superhighways in the abstract; but *via the Orient express* or *via the Mass Pike,* if you are talking about a specific train or superhighway.

If you are talking about a specific telephone, I wouldn't use *via*; I think you have to say something like "I called her on my cell phone."

Comment: Excellent answer, which I have up-voted.

Comment: The usage *via telephone* does occur, but not so often as [via satellite](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=via+telephone%2Cvia+satellite&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Some are for [call via satellite](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+via+satellite%2Ccall+via+telephone&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but people simply don't use *called via telephone*. They use *called by telephone* - or more often, just *telephoned*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the phrase *called via telephone* may sound a little off because it's redundant (how else would you call somebody?). However, *contacted via telephone* sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I'm not saying the usage is *incorrect*, just that it's not "normal". For example, NGram has 150,000 instances of *contact by telephone*, and only 5000 for *contact via telephone*. IMHO *via* is normally used if the communication/travel mode is itself unusual for the context, or where the route passes through a non-standard/contextually significant intermediate point.

Answer (score 3):

Both “I called her via telephone” and “I called her via a telephone” are grammatical (“correct”) English, and they mean approximately the same thing.

The preposition *via* denotes “the way” something happened, either the manner in which it occurs (“we went *via* car”) or some entity that intervened in the action (“we went *via* route 89”). In these examples, the difference is that *telephone* without an article refers to the modality of telephony—that is, communicating using the telephone system, whereas  *a telephone* refers to the specific object used to communicate. In this case, one implies the other—if you communicated using a telephone then you must have communicated using the telephone system, and if you communicated using the telephone system then you must have communicated using a specific telephone, so the phrases are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest another alternative that uses an adverb instead of a prepositional phrase headed with 'via' : what about saying 'call telephonically' ? So in your example:

> I called her telephonically.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22call+her+telephonically%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iTnmVL6aJYLYggTel4CABA#q=%22call+telephonically%22) seems to exhibit this usage's popularity.

Answer (score 0):

The Latin word via means way, path, route and the typical use of via is describing a route as in

1 We travelled to England via Dover.

2 The flight goes via Frankfurt.

3 via satellite

This via is the Latin ablative case approximately meaning on the route of or using the route of.

"via telephone" may be grammatical possible, but it is a stilted and abnormal formulation that shows that the speaker does not know that the use of via is restricted mainly to describing the route.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/via